# What is a Cruise Captain?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots, cruise

I wonder what is a *Cruise Captain*, albeit I assume they are here to fly the cruise phase.

- Differences in responsibility / authority with a Captain?
- From training / certificate standpoint, what is required?
- When are they seen on board?
- Is the Cruise Captain the pilot-in-command when they officiate?

Comment: Can you provide some context to the term, perhaps a link to where you saw the term (an article, movie, book etc.).

Comment: @Dave: In this ARAIC [MD-11F incident report](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/906.pdf) (§2.1): "A total of five persons [...] of which the three were operating crewmembers consisted of a **Pilot In Command** (PIC), a **Co-Pilot** who was qualified as PIC (hereinafter called the Second In Command (SIC), and a **Cruise Captain** as a relief crew [...])".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the discussion here](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=211897) it seems a "cruise captain" is the captain who flies only during the cruise stage of flight. You can find a [job listing for a "cruise captain" here](http://www.rishworthaviation.com/Opportunity/3691/b787-relief-captain-norwegian-type-rated-and-non-type-rated.aspx) but it does not elaborate much on the duties. To act as the pilot in command (at least by FAA regs) they would have to be current, and type certified in the aircraft in question. It seems the term is more a turn of phrase and the regulations are not any different for a cruise captain. On very long haul flights that may require 3 full crews, there will be a crew in the middle section of the flight that never sees takeoff or landing from the cockpit.

The [report you have linked in the comments](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/906.pdf) defines cruise captain in the foot note on page 3.

> Cruise Captain in this report refers to a pilot certificated as cruise
>   captain by the Malaysian Aviation Authority, and is qualified by the
>   company to act as PIC during cruise only and who was engaged in the
>   operation of the aircraft.

It sounds like "Cruise Captain" in this case is a Malaysian Aviation Authority term (although it may apply elsewhere as well). I am looking for the actual regulation that defines it but have not yet come across them.

Answer (score 9):

On long haul flights that require additional crew members, airlines use various ways to meet the regulatory or contract requirements.

Many airlines add just additional First Officers (co-pilots). For some airlines this is not desirable because there is no Captain in command while the Captain takes his break.

Some airlines will add a second Captain on these long haul flights while a few have created a new position they call "Cruise Captain". This is usually a senior First Officer who has additional training and responsibility to satisfy the need to have a "Captain" on the flight deck for all phases of flight without actually paying for full Captain.

Some airlines have also created a junior position called "Cruise Relief Pilot" who is paid less than a regular First Officer and can only operate during the cruise portion of the flight.

Comment: A pilot which only operates during the cruise portion of the flight is......kinda boring, if I might say.

Comment: @kevin My goal is to make every flight as boring as possible.  Exciting flights tend to be fatal.

Comment: _"Many airlines add just additional First Officers"_ Do any airlines actually do this? This would only allow the First Officer to take a break, not the Captain who would be forced to fly the entire flight with no (extended) break. It's not just about having a Captain in command, it's about sitting in the left seat. My understanding is that only someone trained to sit in the left seat is allowed to do so, which a normal First Officer is not. If a First Officer is trained for left seat then they have additional certification as a relief pilot, they are no longer just a First Officer.

Comment: @StevePemberton yes many airlines do it. AF447 is perhaps an argument against it, but a crew of 1 captain and 2-3 first officers (or a second officer) is very common and happens without incident every day. The laws don't require the captain to physically be in the flight deck at all times.

Comment: @Ben - but do they sit in the left seat? I realize that the left seat doesn't have to be occupied at all times, but my understanding is that no one can sit there without being trained for it. I think a First Officer with training for left seat is no longer "just" a First Officer, although the actual terminology for what they are classified as might vary per country/airline. Maybe they are colloquially referred to as First Officers simply because they have not had Captain training, only First Officer training with additional left seat training.

Comment: @StevePemberton yes they do sit in the left seat, that's better than it remaining empty. I can't answer with authority but I think left seat training is only required for takeoff and landing. But left seat training doesn't mean a promotion above first officer. I personally have photos sent from a second officer from the left seat in cruise.

Comment: @Ben - I find it unlikely that this would be allowed even in cruise. In an emergency situation where they suddenly have to at a minimum operate switches, and possibly even fly the plane, it would be extremely dangerous to be sitting there without having done some simulator time in the left seat reacting to emergencies, etc. and getting checked out for operation in the left seat. Although I suppose after enough time sitting there they would eventually gain those reaction skills through osmosis, I don't think that's how the regulatory agencies would view it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a time when crews had 2 Captains (rated and trained on the left seat and 2 First Officers (rated and trained on the right seat). Companies have made measures to cut down on costs in salaries so instead of the usual crewing, they've made it 1 Capt (rated and trained on the left seat), 1 FO (rated and trained on both right and left seat) and 2 Second Officers (rated and trained primarily to fly during cruising phase on the right seat, hence the derivation of the term Cruise Relief Officer or in the case of the First Officer, Cruise Captain. Differences in policies and protocols dictate responsibilities and duties

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).